# Nesting a query that uses Inner Join to a larger query

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I'm trying to append some data to an existing query, but the additional data uses an Inner Join to work correctly. I am struggling to nest it without losing results in the larger query.

The original query is built from many tables, so it takes:

```
select
    T1.key1,
    T1.data1,
    T1.data2,
    T1.data3,
    T2.key1,
    T2.data1,
    T2.data2,
    T2.data3
    ...
from Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 ON T1.key1=T2Key1
JOIN
...

WHERE (criteria).
```

Then there is the second table comes in, where I tried getting the latest date that a specific action occurs by using the following:

```
select
    NewTable.Key1,
    NewTable.Data1,
    NewTable.Data2,
    NewTable.Data3,
    NewTable.Data4,
    NewTable.Data5,
    Table1.Data2,
    Table2.Data3
FROM tablename1 NewTable
INNER JOIN
(
    select Data1, MAX(date) AS DateTime
    FROM tablename1
    WHERE (criteria)
    GROUP BY Key1
) AS NewTable2 ON (NewTable.Key1 = NewTable2.Key1) AND (NewTable.Data1 = NewTable2.Data1)
LEFT JOIN Table 1...
LEFT JOIN Table 2...;
```

Now I want to include this table as part of the data gathering in the first table. I don't need the Table1 & Table2 data, as that is part of the table at the start, but I am struggling to include the second table without loss of data.

What would be the best approach to incorporate this additional data in, given that it needs an Inner Join, that must not impact on the previous data? In essence, I need all the data from the first query regardless of what the second query produces, but the second query needs to be limited to produce the right results?

So far I am using Power Bi to merge the two resulting tables, but wondering if there's a more efficient wat.

Comment: Look into using a CTE to make this easier to write and understand.

Comment: Can you clarify: "given that it needs an Inner Join, that must not impact on the previous data?" ???    "I need all the data from the first query regardless of what the second query produces"  seems like you need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` ?

Comment: A common table expression (CTE) would make it easier (as Joel mentions).  Also, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` to add the second query to the first.  This way you will always get the first set of results and the second set will be there when possible.

Comment: "So far I am using Power Bi to merge the two resulting tables, but wondering if there's a more efficient way.", Yeas a more efficient way would be to learn SQL (and do not rely on the _Power_ of BI, but on your own powers....

Comment: I'm wondering if a window function like `max(case when <conditions> then date end ) over (partition by ...)` may work and avoid the whole sub query.

Comment: It would help a lot did you show some sample data and the expected result. You have confused column names by the way. Here: `select Data1, MAX(date) AS DateTime ... GROUP BY Key1` and here: `(select Data1, MAX(date) AS DateTime ... ) ... AS NewTable2 ON ...NewTable2.Key1 ... NewTable2.Data1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just union both the result set,

```
select
    T1.key1,
    T1.data1,
    T1.data2,
    T1.data3,
    T2.key1,
    T2.data1,
    T2.data2,
    T2.data3
    ...
from Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 ON T1.key1=T2Key1
JOIN
...

WHERE (criteria)

Union all

select
    NewTable.Key1,
    NewTable.Data1,
    NewTable.Data2,
    NewTable.Data3,
    NewTable.Data4,
    NewTable.Data5,
    Table1.Data2,
    Table2.Data3
FROM tablename1 NewTable
INNER JOIN
(
    select Data1, MAX(date) AS DateTime
    FROM tablename1
    WHERE (criteria)
    GROUP BY Key1
) AS NewTable2 ON (NewTable.Key1 = NewTable2.Key1) AND (NewTable.Data1 = NewTable2.Data1)
LEFT JOIN Table 1...
LEFT JOIN Table 2...;
```